# Is Zonaras' epitome of Cassius Dio the fullest surviving ancient annalistic account of Roman history for the period 292–265 BC?

Tags: roman-republic

Is the Byzantine historian [Zonaras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joannes_Zonaras)' epitome of Cassius Dio's   Roman History (as presented alongside Dio's fragments in the Loeb edition of the Roman History) our fullest surviving ancient annalistic account of Roman history for the years 292–265 BC?

To the best of my knowledge, this period also receives  coverage from Dionysius of Halicarnassus, Diodorus Siculus and Appian, though their surviving annalistic narratives are fragmentary.

Is there any other surviving annalistic source that is superior to those mentioned above?

(NB: This discussion is restricted to sources containing full-length annalistic accounts of Roman affairs, excluding Plutarch's Life of Pyrrhus which falls in the genre of biography.)

Comment: Welcome to HistorySE, Rex! What has your research shown you so far? Where have you already searched? Please help us to help you. You might find it helpful to review the site [tour] and [help]. You may improve your
question to comply with site guidelines with an [edit] and the help of [ask].

Comment: Specifically: is this about the *leoquelle* (unidentified sources/parts in the epitome)?

Comment: The whole field of history is based on fragmentary sources, so I'd not reject them out of hand, unless you have a secondary source which has already done the compilation.